# udev rules: IMPORT{cmdline}="nodmraid" - what does that do?

Tags: udev

It's not very clear from the manual what:

`IMPORT{cmdline}="nodmraid"` actually does?

Does it bring in the "nodmraid" command line parameter in to a environment variable named nodmraid or does it just set an environment variable "nodmraid" to "1" or "" or does it just return "1" (but there is no assignment in that case)?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IMPORT{cmdline}="nodmraid"` parses the kernel command line and sets the `nodmraid` property for the device to `1` if the `nodmraid` is present on the boot command line and doesn't have a parameter. If it has a parameter (which doesn't really make sense for `nodmraid`, but you can give it one) it would set the property value to that parameter.

Simple rule to check how exactly `IMPORT{cmdline}` works could look like this:

```
IMPORT{cmdline}="ro"
IMPORT{cmdline}="modprobe.blacklist"
IMPORT{cmdline}="nodmraid"
```

(just picking some random options on the boot command line) and result in `udevadm info`

```
$ udevadm info /dev/sda --query property --property nodmraid,ro,modprobe.blacklist
ro=1
modprobe.blacklist=nouveau
```

`ro` doesn't have a parameter so its value is set to `1`, `modprobe.blacklist` has a parameter (`nouveau`) so its value is set to `nouveau` and `nodmraid` isn't set because I don't have it in my boot parameters.

and if you actually have `nodmraid` on the kernel command line you can actually see it set for all devices to `1` even without the "test" rule above:

```
$ udevadm info /dev/vda1 --query property --property nodmraid
nodmraid=1
```

Comment: That makes since - not just to be clear, your sample IMPORT you put in some rules file and had to reboot?   Those imported values stay around through all the various other rules being loaded? and continue on in some cached form that udevadm can get to?

Comment: You don't need to reboot, all the rules are executed with every udev event (you can trigger your own event with `udevadm trigger <device>`). udev saves everything to its internal database, `IMPORT{cmdline}="xyz"` just adds a new property `xyz` for the device in the database and it is available for all other rules executed after the rule that added the property. My short example adds the property to all devices, you would usually limit it with something like `SUBSYSTEM!="block", GOTO="end"` to skip all non-block devices.